# Integrating youtube playlists in android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I want to integrate youtube playlist in android such that when user open the playlist it displays all the videos of that playlist..Below is the working code of integrating youtube video to android.Here I am providing video id inside loadVideo() method.But i don't know how to integrate playlists..I want to know how to proceed in that ?

```
public class YoutubeActivity2 extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube_api);
        final ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.hide();
        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST)
        {

            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            YPlayer = player;
            YPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
            YPlayer.loadVideo("2zNSgSzhBfM");
            YPlayer.play();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do an Data API call to get the videos of the channel then may create players with those video ids.

Here's an example for that call: https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java#L391